# Legacy VoIP and Background Function Alternatives

Tags: ios, background, voip, appdelegate

I'm updating and Alarm app I have and version 8 of XCode has informed me that "Legacy VoIP background mode is deprecated and no longer supported"...

Which means the alarm function of the app won't work in the background. What are my options for keeping the app running in the background?

Comment: Have you had any luck with this? Looking to do something similar!